# Change emacs comment markers from ;; to //

Tags: emacs, comments

When I am using Emacs to edit a ".s" file, I want to change the comment from ";;" to "//". I can't seem to find out how to change the comment identifiers?

For example, when I comment-region.

More information:
I appear to be in ASM-MODE which is the default mode for editing assembler files. I made sure that I was in asm-mode by

```
 (setq auto-mode-alist                                                                                                 
       (append '(("\\.s$"   . asm-mode)auto-mode-alist))
```

Because assembly programs typically use ; as the comment indicator, asm-mode uses this. However, for some reason I cannot figure the GNU assembler (GNU Binutils for Raspbian) 2.35.2 uses // or @ or # for comments NOT a ;

Therefore, I would like to change the behaviour such that when I select a region and M-X comment-region it uses either // or @ for comments. I cannot use the default comment character, I need to change it to either double-slashes // or an at symbol @

The question is really how do I go about changing the default comment character for in a mode?

Comment: The question could be clearer. Say what mode that buffer is in, or what mode you expect it to be in. Comment chars & style depend on the major mode, by default. The mode you have or want for `.s` files should define commenting appropriately. `;` is the comment-start char for Emacs-Lisp buffers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the major mode of the `.s` file is `asm-mode`, you can use the mode hook to tweak the comment start string:

```
(defun my/asm-comment-tweak ()
  (setq-local comment-start "// "))

(eval-after-load "asm"
  (add-hook 'asm-mode-hook #'my/asm-comment-tweak))
```

Adding the above to your init file should let you open a `.s` file, which will be in `asm-mode`. The last thing that is done by `asm-mode` is to run the mode hook which will call the function `my/asm-comment-tweak`: the function will set the buffer-local variable `comment-start` to the string you specified.

This pattern is *very* common: many problems in customizing emacs are solved in exactly the same way. You define a function that tweaks a variable and you arrange for the function to be called by the appropriate mode hook.